# How can I get win 10 to let me print 5x7 and other sizes like i used to before an update i did not want

Tags: windows-10

How can I get win 10 to let me print 5x7 and other sizes like i used to before an update i did not want
I have an HP Officejet Pro 8600

Comment: You can still use the legacy print screen from the context menu of the image/document you have.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved when I changed my default photo viewer from paint to Gimp.

I will have to remember to make sure that paint (which really starts up fast) is not my photo viewer when I want to print many prictures as 5x7 or whatever.